# Landing Page will not redirect to the Thank You Page for some people

Tags: landing-page

I have been informed that some people 3 to be exact within my company when they complete a form on a landing page, but are not being redirected to the thank you page. However, I tested the landing page and everything appears to be working correctly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Following can be the reason :-

1. User may not have the access to visualforce page.
   check this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325936&type=1) to enable it for certain user.
2. Also check with the Object/Fields permission which you are referring in page. Give permission for those as well if not given permission.

Comment: Is this for salesforce marketing cloud?